# Django: Include a template containing a script tag into another script tag

Tags: javascript, django

**I want include a html file containing a script tag like this:**

`<script>$('#page-content').html('{% include "title.html" %}');</script>`

**title.html:**

`<script>document.title = "Hello World!"</script><p>Hello World!</p>`

**result:**

`<script>$('#page-content').html('<script>document.title = "Hello World!"</script><p>Hello World!</p>');</script>`

Sadly, the browser won't execute it correctly due to the mulitple sets of script tags and I'm not quite sure how to solve it best

Comment: The problem is that your script is not executed? You can use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) if you are already using jQuery (make your script `js` fie instead of `script` in `html` for this).

Comment: Yes, the script won't execute correctly. And the problem is that the HTML file also contains normal HTML tags, also I can't modify the HTML file I want to include

Comment: Why do you need to use the `include` template tag? The content of `title.html` is static so why don't you directly add that to your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just `$.html` will not execute scripts appended, but plain javascript [can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment).

```js
// const content = `{% include 'title.html' %}`;
const content = `<script>alert("foo")</script>`;
const target = document.getElementById('page-content');

const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(target);
const fragment = range.createContextualFragment(content);
target.appendChild(fragment);  // Here script is executed, "foo" pops up
```